# Store column name in variable and use it in query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to take 2 inputs, column name and search keyword, from the user and filter data in the specific column that they have entered. For that I have written this stored procedure:

```
Create proc spGetReference
    @Search nvarchar(255)=Null, --- search Key word
    @Column nvarchar(200)='MainCode' --- Column Name
as
begin
    With CTE_Table as
    (
        Select 
            ROW_NUMBER() over(order by L.MainCode) as RowNum,
            Count(*) over() as TotalRow,
            ReferenceNo,
            MainCode,
            Name,
            SettlementStatus,
            DocumentType
        FROM 
            LcDocArrived L (NOLOCK),
            Master M (NOLOCK)
        WHERE 
            ArrStatus = 'P' 
            AND M.MainCode = L.MainCode 
            AND M.BranchCode = L.BranchCode 
            AND M.BranchCode = '001'
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM CTE_Table 
    WHERE @Search IS NULL
       OR @Column LIKE '%'+@Search+'%' 
end

exec spGetReference 'Ram','Name'
```

This is not showing any records.. I think column name cannot be use like this.

How can I take column Name and use it for filtering data?

Comment: yes, you are right. you should use dynamic sql query

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write it in a dynamic way.

```
        CREATE PROC spGetReference @Search NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
        ,--- search Key word
        @Column NVARCHAR(200) = 'MainCode' --- Column Name
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = ''

    SET @sql = '
;With CTE_Table as
(
    Select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by L.MainCode) as RowNum,
    Count(*) over() as TotalRow,
    ReferenceNo,
    MainCode,
    Name,
    SettlementStatus,
    DocumentType
    FROM LcDocArrived L (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN 
    Master M (NOLOCK) ON M.MainCode = L.MainCode 
    and M.BranchCode = L.BranchCode
    WHERE ArrStatus = ''P'' 
    AND M.BranchCode = ''001''
)
Select  * from CTE_Table where ' + @Search + ' Is null or ' + @Column + ' like ''%' + @Search + '%''
'

    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
END

EXEC spGetReference 'Ram'
    ,'Name'
```

Comment: Please check my edited post. Print the @SQL and review it before execution.

Comment: its showing blank.. it mean @sql is null ..how does it happen

Comment: Please pass some value to both the input variables

Comment: Thank you bro for your kind help.